# Mocking a protected member without reflection

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a member that returns a string from a resource file, and I want to unit test this, as there's quite a few and they could be changed by mistake. I understand that this is achievable using reflection but I've been asked to do it in a way that doesn't use reflection.

The members look something like this;

```
protected override string StringOne
    {
        get
        {
            return Resources.String;
        }
    }
```

I understand that setting up the return for the member can be done as;

```
 mock.Protected()
            .Setup<string>("StringOne")
            .Returns("Returned string.");
```

and .verifiable() can be added to the end of this. But I can't find how to verify that a string is being returned. Or am I right in thinking that the by setting this up with .verifiable(), that the .returns("") value is the expected, and calling

```
mock.Verify();
```

will verifying that the member has returned the correct string or simply that the member was called at some point during the test?

Comment: `Veriffy` just checks that the mocked member was actually called. It will not verify if the mocked member returnes what you set up. You don´t want to check if the mock workes correctly (I guess this should be ensured by MOQ), but if it was actually *called*

Comment: Yeah, I thought it wouldn't be that simple, is there anything incredibly against using Inheritance to derive the class I'm testing from the unit test class?

Comment: You want to derive from your class to test to mock one of its members?

Comment: Just do an assert with the expected and actual result of the test.

Comment: @Nkosi I can't Assert on the expected and actual results as I can't access the member itself to get the actual result because it's protected.

Comment: @HimBromBeere That's one of the options I can see, but I'm not sure if it's bad practice to do so, there are a few other protected methods and members in this particular class that that would allow me to test.

Comment: And for the record just because you are not directly using reflection doesn't mean that the framework being called is not using reflection. If you check the source code of `Moq.Protected` you will see that the framework is in fact using reflection under the hood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you are encountering here is that you are trying to test something that isn't available from outside of the class. Tests should only test the public interface of your class so that the internals of the class can change as long as the public behaviour remains the same.

In this instance, I think that you have two options:

One is to move this code into another class with these properties being public, that way your test can just call the new public properties and check the return and the classes that need to use the value of the property can call your new class. Inheritance is generally not a great way of sharing code anyway (a blog post explaining this concept: http://www.blinkingcaret.com/2016/04/13/composition-superior-inheritance/)

The other is to test where these properties end up being used. For example, if you have some method that passes the value of `StringOne` into another mocked class, you can check that the correct value is passed through or if it ends up being used in a file path, you should test that the file path ends up being correct etc

Comment: Yeah I thought this was going to be the result. I didn't write any of the code and it obviously wasn't written to be tested. I'll just leave the the protected stuff, and if anybody in the future wants to tackle the issue they can! :) thanks for the advice and help guys.