# How to mock a base method in a derived class?

Tags: c#, moq

I want to mock the method `base.Generate(operation, model, builder, false);` of the following code:

```cs
public class ExtendedSqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator : SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator
    {
        public ExtendedSqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator(MigrationsSqlGeneratorDependencies dependencies, IMigrationsAnnotationProvider migrationsAnnotations) :base(dependencies, migrationsAnnotations){}

        // this methode should be tested 
        protected override void Generate(CreateIndexOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder, bool terminate)
        {
            base.Generate(operation, model, builder, false); // this line should be mocked
            AddIncludeIndex(operation, builder, terminate);
        }
        protected void AddIncludeIndex(CreateIndexOperation operation, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder, bool terminate)
        {
            //some code
        }
        public void GenerateTest(CreateIndexOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder, bool terminate)
        {
            Generate(operation, model, builder, terminate);
        }
```

The mock setup I used is:

```
var sut = new Mock<ExtendedSqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator>(GetDependencies(), p2.Object) 
{ 
 CallBase = true 
};
sut.Protected().Setup("Generate", true, ItExpr.IsAny<CreateIndexOperation>(), ItExpr.IsAny<IModel>(), ItExpr.IsAny<MigrationCommandListBuilder>(), ItExpr.IsAny<bool>());
sut.Object.GenerateTest(createIndexOperation.Object, new Model(), m3.Object, false);
```

For the moment I call `GenerateTest()`. 
The problem is that the `Generated` method is mocked and not the `base.Generate` I also tried to setup a derived TestClass, which allow me to call the protected methode from the testclass. But with the same problem.

This is not the same as [Mocking a protected member without reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41161353/mocking-a-protected-member-without-reflection). I know how to mock a call to a base class methode but not how to mock the same methode.

**Some background information about this class**

EF can generate SQL statements based on Model. To extend the generated SQL I replaced this class in the DI with the derived class. When EF call `generate`, I have to call the base class and than add some extra SQL statements.

The reason that I want to mock `base.generate' is

- it is not easy to configure valid parameters
- I am not interested in the implementation detail of the base class.

This scenario seems not unique and expected there is a simple way to mock this.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to why you're trying to mock the implementation in the base class to begin with. If you're properly mocking your implementation of the Generate method, the base class Generate method shouldn't be called at all. Am I wrong?

Comment: I Added some comment to the code which methode I want to test and which base call should be mocked. Makes this more clear.

Comment: Hmm.. So the question I'm asking myself is if this is something Mock is designed to help you with. This framework helps you to remove dependencies, but in this case you're trying to remove the dependency on the base class, which is just a strange concept to get my head around, especially if/because the base.Generate() method has side effects. At the same time, though, I get that there are cases where the base method makes system calls that you'd rather avoid..

Comment: Take a look at the second answer in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28223976/moq-a-base-class-function-from-a-derived-class). I think this is echoing in part my feelings here. My gut reaction is that because of all the side effects you'd see in practice, better is to run Integration tests with LocalDb

Answer (score 0):

While I think the problem you're trying to solve can very much valid in the broad sense, especially when the base class makes system/IO calls you want to avoid, I'd point on the responses in [this previous related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28223976/moq-a-base-class-function-from-a-derived-class) to suggest that Moq is not the right tool here.

Moq is designed to remove dependencies from your sut, not to replace functionality from it. And this makes sense, because functions within your sut often have side effects (especially when the return type of the function you're trying to replace is void).

Historically, when I'm doing testing of this nature with EF, I find it more convenient and reliable to spin up a localDb per test class (or test assembly) and perform integration tests instead of attempting to unit test for the sake of unit testing. Of course, there are dependencies here that you're using code-first with migrations, etc..